# Python Key Error Appending Dictionary to Dictionary with list

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, keyerror, praw

I'm losing my mind here. What I am trying to do here is pull up a Reddit threads from a csv file that is already generated, then pull the title of the thread, the number of comments, and the current date and time and append it into the first dictionary. Then what I try to do is remove the punctuation's(which I am also still kind of failing at) and encoding. Lastly append each value from the first dictionary into the second one so that each thread from the first dictionary could have their own individual csv file.

TLDR: Im getting a key error when appending the first dict to the second dict, can anyone help? Also improve my chances of removing punctuations?

```
import csv
import praw
import os
import errno
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

thread_id = []


volume_dict = { "post":['These', 'are', 'values'], 
               "num_comments":['62', '43', '96'], 
               "date_time":[]
           }
volume_dict2 = { "post2":[], 
               "num_comments":[], 
               "date_time":[]
           } 


for post in volume_dict["post"]:
    volume_dict2['post2'].append(post)
    volume_dict2['num_comments'].append(volume_dict['num_comments'])
    volume_dict2['date_time'].append(dt.datetime.now())

    pathV = os.path.join(os.getcwd() + post + '.csv')

    volume_data = pd.DataFrame(volume_dict2)
    volume_data.to_csv(pathV, index=True)
    print('saved to' + pathV)
    volume_dict2.clear()
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation (badly indented Python code is totally meaningless) and post a proper MCVE.

Comment: by MCVE I think bruno means a [mcve]

Comment: you don't need to use those backslashes `\\` when defining dictionaries and when passing arguments to a function

Comment: I tried bumping down the code a bit

Comment: Ah ok ill remove the backslashes I saw it on an example

Comment: please update sample input with some dummy values which can give better idea... and also volume_dict2['num_comments'][count].append(volume_dict['num_comments'])   what do u mean by `[count]` ?

Comment: Sorry I was just testing something to see if that would fix the Key Error. I'll update the code with some values

Comment: print(volume_dict["post"][count]) <-- aren't you getting error for this also ?

Comment: No error there it prints everything from the list. I should actually take that out since its just the second for loop where I am having issues

Answer (score 0):

punctuation part:

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the
>   first count occurrences are replaced.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> punch = string.punctuation
>>> strg = 'bad{-<+>-}pun'.replace(punch,'')
>>> strg
'bad{-<+>-}pun'
>>> for p in punch:
...     strg = strg.replace(p,'')
...
>>> strg
'badpun'
```